# List all websites from a certain domain

Tags: web-crawler

i have a school project where I have to list all websites from my country's government (.gov.pt) and i am trying to think of the best way to get that accomplished ... can someone help me ? my teacher suggested either creating a web crawler or manually searching the websites, basically we can use anything we want to achieve it

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Could use Python with Beautiful Soup to scrape  information. Very easy to use, when you know what information you want to scrape.

Comment: just googled that and from what I could understand Beautiful Soup focus more on web scraping than on web crawling